# Allow reputation from one site to set privileges on another

Tags: feature-request

I have roughly 1250 reputation on StackOverflow. I joined one of the other sites and was given  starting points of 100. So far so good. I posted a question, and I offered my 100 points as a bounty. After posting the question, people would ask questions to me in the comments, and I could not answer because I no longer had enough points.

First off, not being able to comment on my own question is an issue isn't it? Secondly, can't the logic here be modified? Take the max(reputation) from all sites. Realize I'm not trying to spam/troll, and allow me to comment.

Some things like tags and moderating I can certainly see should go off the reputation only on that one site. But other items could really be expanded to cover more.

Comment: From the [SO Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment): "Please note that you can *always* comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on *other people's* posts is a privilege."

Comment: Sorry. Looks like you are correct. I found my question was a duplicate and I added a bounty to someone else's question. I still think I should be able to comment for having reputation on other sites. Also, the fact that I added a bounty should have done it. The question was here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53520/why-is-someone-not-allowed-to-see-my-private-video-on-youtube-even-though-i-have

Comment: Sharing privileges across sites has been proposed before; see, for example, [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158694/any-non-domain-specific-privileges-earned-should-be-shared-across-all-sites) on Meta SE. On the other hand, I can't find any past feature requests to allow comments when you post a bounty on someone else's question; perhaps you could make that the focus of your post?

Comment: You may want to edit your question to clarify the bounty issue.

Comment: Sharing privileges across sites probably wont gain any ground, but you may have something where it comes to commenting on questions you've invested a bounty on.

Comment: I agree that reputation stinks. Some things should be about post score. Some things should be about comment score. Some things should be about tag score. Some things should be about approved edits…

Comment: @bjb568: No, reputation (and the related privileges) keep out the riffraff. Privileges have to be earned because it shows you've spent enough time participating in the site to have earned them, and also shows you've spent enough time to hopefully understand how to *use them* once you've earned them. (This is also why they don't transfer across sites; what you know about one SE site may not be the same on other sites. While I'm quite familiar with SO and Meta, I don't spend any time on [engineering.se], and don't expect to have any beneficial comments to make there if I visit.

Comment: @KenWhite I didn't say everyone should have all privileges. I'm saying that upvoted answers doesn't make you a better moderator or commenter.

Comment: @bjb568: No, you said "reputation stinks". Posting answers shows participation, and upvotes shows that your participation is considered useful. Read again what I wrote. You *earn privileges* by *participating* and earning reputation for that participation. You don't earn reputation (or privileges) by just posting noise.

Comment: @bjb568: I don't know why you're being rude here. I said nothing that was directed at you personally, and I did not get rude with you at all. If you don't want to hear what people think of your comments, don't post them. This is a public site, and anything you post here is open for discussion by others. I disagree with your vague statement that "reputation stinks", and I disagree with your position that you should just automatically be granted *any* sort of privilege on other sites based on the reputation earned on another except for the trust shown by association bonuses.

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, I was just frustrated. Deleted.

Answer (score 7):

No, reputation should not translate so literally. What happens now with the Association Bonus is that it unlocks the most basic limitations and indicates that we know the *software*, but not that we know the *culture*:

[image]

Now... you bountied yourself out of the trusted user comfort zone. If you're ready to spend the reputation, you've got to be ready to go bellow the previous privileges.

It doesn't even need to be network wide, if we have 525 reputation in a given main site and bounty some question to the fullest 500 points, *goodbye Comment Everywhere*...

At the end, [looks like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260941/allow-reputation-from-one-site-to-set-privileges-on-another#comment44712_260941) your issue is being able to comment in a 3rd party question where you did set a bounty, [as noted by apaul34208](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260941/allow-reputation-from-one-site-to-set-privileges-on-another#comment44723_260941).

Comment: Does it really work this way? I tried commenting on a question on Meta Stack Exchange recently, and was denied permission. Is Meta SE different?

Comment: You must have another account, only **one** shows here: http://stackexchange.com/users/4322362/reto-koradi?tab=accounts

Comment: Hmm, that was probably a misunderstanding on my side then. I had never realized that I needed to sign up separately for each of the sub-sites. I thought I could just click on one of the other sites and start using it. When I click on "comment" on Meta SE, it says that it "requires an account with +1 rep". I focused on the "+1 rep" part, and didn't realize that I didn't even have an account. Sorry about not reading more carefully, this all makes sense now.